# How to bring old instance of calculator on top of every other window?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments

I would like to open the calculator. If calculator already opened then want to bring in front of all other windows... without using any coding of hotkey.

I used the following script:

```
@echo off

start /b calc.exe
```

Note: As mentioned, I want to bring the old instance in front.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer :** 
 not possible with batch script

However you can do it with [VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781931/locking-focus-on-batch-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) or use [AutoHot Key](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm)
I see that you don't want any coding of a hotkey so i believe VBScript will be your solution here

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate "Calculator"
```

You will need to start the VBScript via your batch script

Comment: PloxPanda: One more question.. if user want to specify the path of any user defined exe instead , then how can we write the same? suppose exe name is "abc.exe" and it is on some specific folder, then how can we do the same –

Comment: You should be able to use the file path in bath like start C:\Program files\Itunes\itunes.exe or Vbs should be objShell.Run("c:\Program Files\itunes\itunes.exe") as long as you have the path you should ve able to open it :)

Comment: I tried that option as well already, but if the application is in background, then objShell.Run() won't bring the application to front of all the windows.

Comment: Hey @VickyCool Sorry about the Late reply This may be able to fix your [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266509/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) Doing this though you may need to make the batch script start the VBScript when it detects calc is open so it will make it focus. Its the first awnser with the green tick :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and then:

```
nircmd win activate "titleofwindow"
```

so basically you need to know the title of the window (Calculator)

also there is `SetActiveWindow` [(see more here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646311(VS.85).aspx) like:

```
HWND WINAPI SetActiveWindow(
_In_ HWND hWnd
);
```

or another solution with [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) - [see here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm)

Comment: Thanks all for your timely response

PloxPanda: without using any third party application I am able to solve using vbscript..Thanks alot.

Comment: I am looking forward to open a user defined executable which is existing in specific folder structure and make sure if previous instance already opened , then it will appear in front of all the windows ...